# How to setup a relationship between the presenting View Controller and the presented View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm still learning objective-c and having a difficult time dismissing presented VCs from presenting VCs.

I read that to achieve this, you establish delegates to send the right messages back to the presenting VC from the presented VC.

My storyboard looks like so:
[image]

The issue I have is if I click UIBUtton2, it doesn't go back to Main VC. In fact, it does nothing.

However, clicking on any cells from VC1 segue to VC2 and clicking on UIButton3 transition back to VC1 as achieved.

MainVC.h:

```
#import "VC1.h"
@interface MainVC : UIViewController <VC1Delegate>
....
```

MainVC.m:

```
- (void)didGoBackToMainVC
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

....
```

VC1 .h:

```
#import "VC2.h"
@protocol VC1Delegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)didGoBackToMainVC;

@end

@interface VC1 : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,
VC2Delegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <VC1Delegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)UIButton2:(UIButton *)sender;
```

VC1.m:

```
- (void)didGoBackToVC1
{   
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)UIButton2:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.delegate didGoBackToMainVC];
}
```

VC2.h:

```
@protocol VC2Delegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)didGoBackToVC1;

@end

@interface VC2 : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <VC2Delegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)UIButton3:(UIButton *)sender;
```

VC2.m:

```
- (IBAction)UIButton3:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.delegate didGoBackToSponsors];
}
```

I'm sure I'm not understanding this relationship properly. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need delegates to do this. If UIButton2 has the code, [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil], it should work. When you call that method on self, it's automatically forwarded to the presenting view controller.

Comment: I didn't originally do delegates, as I used code for UIButton, but upon transitioning from VC2 back to VC1, I get the "attempting to present VC1 on VC2 whose view is not in the window hierarchy", so I started using delegates

Comment: That shouldn't happen, if you do it correctly. Without seeing your code, I can't see what you were doing incorrectly.

Comment: I used "Present Modally" segue to transition from MainVC to VC1 so no code for UIBUtton1. With UIButton2 and UIButton3, the only code I used to go from VC1 to MainVC and VC2 to VC1 was "[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];" in the IBAction code. And that's where the error occurred.

Comment: That should have worked -- that code is correct. Did you have any segues attached to those buttons as well?

Comment: omg I'm such an IDIOT, I didn't realize till now that I had a segue on UIButton2. thank you for fixing my stupidity!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your comments above I saw that your Main VC shows VC1 Modally correctly.
So I guess you have this code in your VC1.m

```
- (IBAction)goToMainVC:(id)sender
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Next make sure your Cell in VC1 has 'Triggered Seques' Selection type of 'Show'. And you probably had this code in your VC1.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushVC2"]) {

    VC2 *vc2 = (VC2 *)segue.destinationViewController;

  }
}
```

Next in your VC2.m you also should have this

```
- (IBAction)dismissVC2:(id)sender
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If these are all you have, it should work like a charm. And no Delegates needed in this case. Hope this helps.